# How to find the size of an ϵ-net of a vector space?

Tags: general-topology, probability-distributions, neural-networks, dimension-theory-analysis, concentration-of-measure

Taken from paper ["A Universal Law of Robustness via isoperimetry"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.12806.pdf) by Bubeck and Sellke.

**Theorem 3.** Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a class of functions from $\mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $\left(x_{i}, y_{i}\right)_{i=1}^{n}$ be i.i.d. input-output pairs in $\mathbb{R}^{d} \times[-1,1]$. Fix $\epsilon, \delta \in(0,1)$.

Assume that:

1. The function class can be written as $\mathcal{F}=\left\{f_{\boldsymbol{w}}, \boldsymbol{w} \in \mathcal{W}\right\}$ with $\mathcal{W} \subset \mathbb{R}^{p}$, $\operatorname{diam}(\mathcal{W}) \leq W$ and for any $\boldsymbol{w}_{1}, \boldsymbol{w}_{2} \in \mathcal{W}$,
   $$
   \left\|f_{\boldsymbol{w}_{1}}-f_{\boldsymbol{w}_{2}}\right\|_{\infty} \leq J\left\|\boldsymbol{w}_{1}-\boldsymbol{w}_{2}\right\|
   $$
2. The distribution $\mu$ of the covariates $x_{i}$ can be written as $\mu=\sum_{\ell=1}^{k} \alpha_{\ell} \mu_{\ell}$, where each $\mu_{\ell}$ satisfies c-isoperimetry.
3. The expected conditional variance of the output is strictly positive, denoted $\sigma^{2}:=\mathbb{E}^{\mu}[\operatorname{Var}[y \mid x]]>0$.\newline

Then, with probability at least $1-\delta$ with respect to the sampling of the data, one has simultaneously for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$ :
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f\left(x_{i}\right)-y_{i}\right)^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\epsilon \Rightarrow \operatorname{Lip}(f) \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2^{9} \sqrt{c}} \sqrt{\frac{n d}{p \log \left(60 W J \epsilon^{-1}\right)+\log (4 / \delta)}} .
$$

**Proof.** Define $\mathcal{W}_{L} \subseteq \mathcal{W}$ by $\mathcal{W}_{L}=\left\{\boldsymbol{w} \in \mathcal{W}: \operatorname{Lip}\left(f_{\boldsymbol{w}}\right) \leq L\right\}$. Denote $\mathcal{W}_{L, \epsilon}$ for an $\frac{\epsilon}{6 J}$-net of $\mathcal{W}_{L}$. We have in particular $\left|\mathcal{W}_{\epsilon}\right| \leq\left(60 W J \epsilon^{-1}\right)^{p}$. We apply Theorem 2 to $\mathcal{F}_{L, \epsilon}=\left\{f_{\boldsymbol{w}}, \boldsymbol{w} \in \mathcal{W}_{L, \epsilon}\right\}$ :

This continues .........

I feel curious  to know the size of a $\epsilon$-net Vector Space.

> How $\left|\mathcal{W}_{\epsilon}\right| \leq\left(60 W J \epsilon^{-1}\right)^{p}$???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\mathcal{W}_{L} \subset \mathcal{W}$ and $\mathrm{diam}(\mathcal{W}) \leq W$, then $\mathcal{W}_{L}$ is contained in a ball of radius $W$. Without loss of generality, let's assume this ball is centered around $0$. Furthermore, denote $r \mathbf{B}_2^d$ for the Euclidean ball of radius $r$ in $d$ dimensions.

The $\varepsilon$-covering number of a Euclidean ball of radius $W$ in $p$ dimensions at most (see [Chapter 4.2 in Roman Vershynin's *High-Dimensional Probability*](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf)):

$$
\mathcal{N}(W\mathbf{B}_2^p, \epsilon) \leq \left(1 + \frac{2W}{\varepsilon}\right)^p \leq \left( \frac{3 W}{\varepsilon 2} \right)^p
$$

Substituting $\varepsilon := \frac{\epsilon}{6J}$ above gives you

$$
\mathcal{N}\left(W\mathbf{B}_2^p, \frac{\epsilon}{6J}\right) \leq
\left(\frac{9 J W}{\epsilon} \right)^p.
$$

Finally, use approximate monotonicity of covering numbers (Exercise 4.2.10 in the book linked above) to deduce

$$
\mathcal{W}_{L} \subset W \mathbf{B}_2^p \Rightarrow
\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{W}_{L}, \epsilon / 6J) \leq
\mathcal{N}(W\mathbf{B}_{2}^p, \epsilon / 12J) \leq
\left( \frac{18 J W}{\epsilon} \right)^p.
$$

Comment: I have one doubt. In vershynin's book it is given for unit radius ball. How have you used it for W/2 radius ball. Also radius should be W/2

Comment: I was able to use it for the radius-$W$ ball since an $\epsilon$-cover for a radius-1 ball can be turned to a $r \epsilon$-cover for a ball of radius $r$ by just scaling both sets by a factor of $r$. Yes, I think you're right about the ball having radius $W/2$.

Comment: Check once the edited version. I think it is correct now.